# VBA Excel- vlookup and based on values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

New to VBA so maybe a rookie question.

I have 2 sheets with a lot of data on stocks for 2 dates. The first column tells me the product, but the 1st sheet has subproducts while the second one is more general. I want to do a table to compare both sheets, but I several subproducts have to be summed to compare with sheet2. Assuming I have a sheet with the mapping, how can I compare it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us a better example of what fields exist in each sheet?

Comment: Product, daily profit, total profit, dividends

Comment: Please include your code in the post, and give us a clear problem statement. What's not working exactly? Or did you even *try* something? See [ask] and [mcve]. "I need XYZ, can someone help me" isn't a valid question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a vlookup on your sub product sheet which maps each sub product to the parent product.

You can then insert a column next to your parent product values, sumif formula to calculate the sum of sub products based on the parent product they are mapped to.

Don't see the need to do this in vba unless it's part of a wider automated process?

Hope this helps.